# Strange issue with Google Maps display

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am facing a strange issue with my app - if I specify a wrong API Key, I get an authentication error as expected but when I specify the right key, I don't get any error message but just a blank screen. What is even more strange is that when I use the same Google Play Services project in a test project, the map loads and is displayed properly.

I have set the Build Target as 21 for both my app as well as the Test project. Please let me know if you might know the reason. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check you've put the API key into the correct google_maps_api.xml. It me a couple of hours to notice there are two. One for Debug and one for Release.

Comment: I am using Eclipse, that does not seem to contain this xml file. And as I mentioned, my test project is working fine with the same Google Play Services, that is really making me very frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the reason - all the processing was done on the UI thread, and my phone being slower, was dropping the UI processing. Moved most of the logic to a separate thread and the map started to get displayed.